# Android Notification User Input

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

What code do I need to add to make an Android notification have a user input option? (Similar to an SMS quick reply option in the notification bar)

Comment: On Android 7.0+ devices, or for Android Wear, [use `RemoteInput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RemoteInput.html). Otherwise, there is no user input option directly in the `Notification` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first show a notification:

```
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );

            // Add to your action, enabling Direct Reply for it
            NotificationCompat.Action action =
                    new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_stat_social_notifications_on, replyLabel, resultPendingIntent)
                            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                            .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
                            .build();

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .addAction(action)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_social_notifications_on)
                            .setContentTitle("DevDeeds Says")
                            .setContentText("Do you like my tutorials ?");

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //Show it
            mNotificationManager.notify(mRequestCode, mBuilder.build());
```

This is a layout for your notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_notification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="replynotification.direct.app.directreplynotification.NotificationActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/replyMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From Intent we will get entered message by key key_text_reply

```
public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Key for the string that's delivered in the action's intent.
    private static final String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";

    // mRequestCode allows you to update the notification.
    int mRequestCode = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.replyMessage);
        textView.setText(getMessageText(getIntent()));

        String returnMessage = "Thank you";

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_toggle_check_box)
                        .setContentText(returnMessage);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //update notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(mRequestCode, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private CharSequence getMessageText(Intent intent) {
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            return remoteInput.getCharSequence(KEY_TEXT_REPLY);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Reference.](http://devdeeds.com/android-reply-notification-directly/)

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize `remoteInput`?